# Circular buffers (start value gets removed, what happens?)

Tags: arrays, queue, circular-buffer

I'm trying to get my head around Circular/ring buffers and I'm a little stuck on a question.

If I have a linear queue such as the following:

66,    20,      30,      40,      19,      empty slot
  0          1           2           3           4               5

**Front: 0 (being 66), back: 5, length: 5**

If a value gets removed (considering 0 was the first to get added, I believe 0 (which is 66), would be removed.

**My question:** Would 20 become the first in the queue then? And how would the layout be after that? Would anything move, e.g. indexes/pointers, or anything of that nature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You'd have something similar to the below:

```
__   20   30   40   19   __
0    1    2    3    4    5
```

**Front: 1, back: 5, length: 4**

Notice that you could even have left the '66' in the position 0 (no need to "erase" it), which is what most implementations do. The **first** item in the queue is the one pointed by the "front" index, not necessarily the first item in the array which is backing the queue.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. The only particular resource that I could find was Wikipedia. Is there anything else out there that explains circular buffers more in depth? Or are circular buffers not as complex and Wikipedia sufficiently covers the topic?

Comment: The description on Wikipedia is fairly good. Circular buffers aren't that complex - mostly arrays with pointers for the next first and next elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 20 would be next in queue then. Your other question depends on the implementation. If coded in such a way, things could move; however this basically defeats the purpose of a circular buffer. In a most normal implementation, only the head and tail pointers would move.